# How do I keep my shoes from rolling around my feet while trail running?

Tags: shoes, footwear, running

This summer I started running on trails through the woods, and I'm loving it.  Problem is, running on trails seems to involve a lot more lateral force on the soles of my feet, mostly from sharp turns and trails that bank the wrong way.

As a result, my shoes tend to slip around my feet.  I've been tying them quite tightly to counteract this effect, but they still roll a little bit when I push off sideways.  These shoes have been fine for many miles on pavement; the problem has only arisen on trails.

It's gotten to the point the shoes have formed themselves into a slumped over shape - this is the direction they slip due to lateral forces:
[image: Example rolled shoe]

Is there anything I can do to make this pair of shoes hold up better? If not, what can I look for in my next pair of shoes to avoid this problem going forward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to invest in an actual pair of **trail running shoes**, they are stiffer, and snugger, and compensate for all of the issue that you're having with your road runners there.

I have a pair of asics trail runners:

[image]
<sup>asics gel fuji trabuco 3</sup>

They have a surprisingly stiff shank in the sole, they are snug even when not laced, and are extremely stable. See here for more info on what to look for in trail running shoes: [Choose your trail runners](https://www.mec.ca/en/explore/choose-your-trail-runners/)

I also recommend learning how to tie a **lace lock** if you don't already, it really helps keep your heel in place.

Comment: Ahh nice - the stiffer material on the sides is pretty clearly visible in this photo.

Comment: @JohnWalthour You'll be surprised by the difference running in a good pair of trail runners makes.

Comment: A good pair of cross country "spikes" or, offroad racing shoes would do well if you're looking for something lighter, and for a bit more control. The 1/4" steel spikes can be replaced with shorter versions and/or plastic if you encounter many wooden bridges or pavement.

Answer (score 2):

Trail runners, cross trainers, and court (tennis) shoes have better side support that will help prevent this.